# Azure function cosmos db output using local.settings.json

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Having a look through the documentation on azure functions, specifically [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-integrate-store-unstructured-data-cosmosdb). It's very clear how to setup integrations via the portal, but developing locally is very vague.

My code is structured below as follows:

```
[FunctionName("foobar")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("foo")]Foo myQueueItem, out object dbFoo)
{
  //do cool stuff here
}
```

The queue trigger works very well with the Azure storage emulator but there are no instructions on how to setup the **local.settings.json**. The file that was auto-generated via visual studio and looks like:

```
{
   "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
   }
}
```

Where would the connection information for cosmos db sit within this structure to enable the function to operate correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should look like this:

```cs
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("foo")] Foo myQueueItem, 
    [DocumentDB("MyDB", "MyCollection", ConnectionStringSetting = "MyConnectionString")]
    out object dbFoo)
```

and the config would be:

```cs
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "MyConnectionString": "...your cosmos db string..."
    }
}
```

In Azure, you would have to put `MyConnectionString` parameter to App Settings.

Update: In V2 version of Functions `DocumentDB` binding attribute was replaced by `CosmosDB` attribute, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb).

Comment: Thanks, that's the workaround I've discovered since, but that's not what they're explaining to do in the linked doucment. They use an out parameter to write to cosmos: `public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, out object taskDocument, TraceWriter log)`

Comment: So do I, I also used out parameter. What's the difference?

Comment: Apologies I know the out is consistent between what you said and the article, but from what I gathered from their article the `[DocumentDB]` attribute is not required. I'm expecting to hear from one of their engineers so if this is the recommended way then I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: If you use attributes to mark your bindings, this attribute is required for output binding. But it's ok, you can wait for others to contribute.

Comment: @Mikhail has the correct answer. Attributes are required when writing your function locally in Visual Studio. The document you linked to discusses how to write your function in the portal, which does not use attributes. Instead, it stores the metadata in a function.json file that lives next to your function code.

Comment: @brettsam might be helpful to indicate this on said document. After all trying it out locally is usually a precursor to getting into azure. Would be helpful to clear up confusion.

Comment: For .NET Core Functions, use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.CosmosDBAttribute` in 3.0.0-beta7 of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` assembly instead of the `DocumentDBAttribute`. This took a while to figure out. See https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/94, https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2598#issuecomment-378304970, and https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2598#issuecomment-385565610 for the trail I took to get it working.